# Manually set scale of scale_fill_distiller()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a series of plots for comparison. Say for example, I wanted to use the `iris` data set to make a plot like this where I have filtered to view only the setosa species:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

iris %>%
  filter(Species=="setosa") %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = Sepal.Width, x = Sepal.Length, fill = Petal.Length)) +
  geom_tile(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral")
```

[image]

Now if I want to plot the versicolor species in the same way I can do it like this:

```
iris %>%
  filter(Species=="versicolor") %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = Sepal.Width, x = Sepal.Length, fill = Petal.Length)) +
  geom_tile(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral")
```

[image]

My issue is that the fill scales are different for these plot. I know I could `facet_wrap` these to solve this but let's just say I need individual plots. What I would like is to apply the same fill scale to both plots. Ideally I'd like to keep using `scale_fill_distiller` but I wasn't able to get very far as the values argument is a bit different for that function, so I tried `scale_fill_gradientn`. First I established a `fill_range` like so:

```
fill_range <- seq(min(iris$Petal.Length), max(iris$Petal.Length), by=0.2)
```

Then I tried inputting the seq into the values argument in `scale_fill_gradientn` like this:

```
iris %>%
  filter(Species=="versicolor") %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = Sepal.Width, x = Sepal.Length, fill = Petal.Length)) +
  geom_tile(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = terrain.colors(length(fill_range)),
                         values=fill_range)

iris %>%
  filter(Species=="setosa") %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = Sepal.Width, x = Sepal.Length, fill = Petal.Length)) +
  geom_tile(stat = "identity")  +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = terrain.colors(length(fill_range)),
                       values=fill_range)
```

Neither of these produced a desired result, plotting a bunch of grey tiles and each with one green one.

Does anyone have an idea where I can manually specify the scale for `scale_fill_distiller"? If that is not possible, can anyone see where I have gone wrong with`scale_fill_gradientn`?

Comment: Does setting the limits for the fill in each plot give the desired result?  Like `limits = c(min(iris$Petal.Length), max(iris$Petal.Length))` in `scale_fill_distiller`.

Comment: Ha! So simple that I completely over-complicated this. If you want to put it as an answer I'll accept it right away. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can set the `limits` to be the same in both plots within `scale_fill_distiller`.

Using the `min` and `max` of `Petal.Length` as the limits:

```
iris %>%
    filter(Species=="setosa") %>%
    ggplot(aes(y = Sepal.Width, x = Sepal.Length, fill = Petal.Length)) +
    geom_tile(stat = "identity") +
    scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral", 
                         limits = c(min(iris$Petal.Length), max(iris$Petal.Length)))
```

[image]

```
iris %>%
    filter(Species=="versicolor") %>%
    ggplot(aes(y = Sepal.Width, x = Sepal.Length, fill = Petal.Length)) +
    geom_tile(stat = "identity") +
    scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral", 
                         limits = c(min(iris$Petal.Length), max(iris$Petal.Length)))
```

[image]