# How to rescale color mapping in scale_color_distiller (ggplot2)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, scale

My data consists of three numeric variables. Something like this:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x= rnorm(10000), y= rnorm(10000))
df$col= df$x + df$y + df$x*df$y
```

Plotting this as a heatplot looks good:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, col= col)) + geom_point(size= 2) + scale_color_distiller(palette = "Spectral")
```

[image: Heatplot normal data]

But real variables can have some skewness or outliers and this totally changes the plot. After `df$col[nrow(df)] <- 100` same `ggplot` code as above returns this plot:

[image]

Clearly, the problem is that this one point changes the scale and we get a plot with little information. My solution is to rank the data with `rank()` which gives a reasonable color progression for any variable I`ve tried so far. See here:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, col= rank(col))) + geom_point(size= 2) + scale_color_distiller(palette = "Spectral")
```

[image: Ranked data with outlier]

The problem with this solution that the new scale (2,500 to 10,000) is shown as the color label. I want the original scale to be shown as color label (o to 10). Therefor, I want that the color progression corresponds to the ranked data; i.e. I need to somehow map the original values to the ranked color values. Is that possible? I tried to [change `limits`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38492029/manually-set-scale-of-scale-fill-distiller) argument to `limits= c(0, 10)` inside `scale_color_distiller()` but this does not help.

Sidenotes: I do not want to remove the outlier. Ranking works well. I wan to use `scale_color_distiller()`. If possible, I want not to use any additional packages than ggplot2.

Comment: maybe you wanna rescale by log transformation. not sure if transforming to rank will always accurately reflect the distribution of your data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increase resolution of color scale for values close to zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20581746/increase-resolution-of-color-scale-for-values-close-to-zero)

Comment: @tjebo Yes, there are [different ways](https://www.datanovia.com/en/lessons/transform-data-to-normal-distribution-in-r/) to normalize data. For my purpose using rank is alright.

Comment: @tjebo The link answers how to better show differences in data with color. This is not my problem as I solved it for me with `rank`. Further, I tried it different ways but I can not figure out how to include the `rescale(...)` solution from your link in `scale_color_distiller()`. Is this the suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rescale the rank to the range of your original df$col.

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10000), y = rnorm(10000))
df$col= df$x + df$y + df$x*df$y
df$col[nrow(df)] <- 100


df %>%
  mutate(
    scaled_rank = scales::rescale(rank(col), range(col))
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, col = scaled_rank)) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  scale_color_distiller(palette = "Spectral")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: But isn't that terribly wrong? This "solution" just plots colours according to the rank, but the legend scales the rank to the original scale. This new figure has many blue points. According to the scale, this corresponds to values below -5. In the original figure, the number of points with values below -5 was small. Thus, the new figure carries a very different message.

Comment: @jarauh yes and no - the ranks are squished into the data range. You would expect different (smaller) distances between the values. You are right in saying that the visualised values are not the same as the original data - but this was not what the question was about. The intention is not to show the original data, but their ranks. This is a different way of showing the data, and it needs to be made very clear to the reader, but I believe it's not "wrong". I have updated the answer to reflect the actual problem of the OP better and included the outlier of "100".

Comment: @jarauh on the other hand, with your background you're much more "number expert" than I am. If you have any objection to my argument, I'd be more than curious to hear it :)

Comment: Thanks. Now it looks fine to me, in fact. Now the scale in the legend makes it clear that the numbers correspond to the rank, not to the original values.